# When I pull the k8s related scheduler code, I always report an error. How can I solve it?

Tags: go, kubernetes, client-go

My goproxy config: `https://goproxy.cn,direct`

When I try to: `go get k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/scheduler/framework`
And then show error: `go: k8s.io/api@v0.0.0: reading k8s.io/api/go.mod at revision v0.0.0: git ls-remote -q origin`

Whow should I do?

At the same time, I found that the k8s code cannot be pulled by using `go get`. How should I solve it? Please help!

Comment: `go get` accepts a module path. The module path is `k8s.io/kubernetes`. What happen if you run `go get k8s.io/kubernetes`?

Comment: That's bad.It just seems to be stuck there, I'm guessing it's timed out, but I really don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Can you run the command with the `-x` flag and share the output? `go get -x k8s.io/kubernetes`

Comment: When I run command `go get -x k8s.io/kubernetes`，And then: `go: k8s.io/api@v0.0.0: reading k8s.io/api/go.mod at revision v0.0.0: git ls-remote -q origin `